# How to align text and image in list tag

Tags: html, css

I've tried vertical-align, display: table-cell, etc everything I could find but I just can't get the text align at the bottom of the list tag...

How would you do it??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/EAUcW/710/ Here is my code

Comment: could show tell what output you should expect show the image or briefly explain it

Comment: I'm trying to get the text on the bottom line of the image

Comment: you will need to remove `float:left` from `img` as `img` and `span` is a `inline` element you can simply align the text by adding `vertical-align:bottom` to `img` demo -  https://jsfiddle.net/EAUcW/715/

Answer (score 0):

remove your float style from the image `#port_wrap img` and add `<br>` before `<strong>`

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/EAUcW/716/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EAUcW/719/)**

```css
#port_wrap {
 margin-top: 130px;
 margin-left: -400px;
 margin-bottom: 150px;
 width: 950px;
 height: 700px; 
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: auto;
}
#port_wrap img {
 border-radius: 10px;
display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
 margin-right: 20px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #888;
}
#port_wrap ul {
 font-family: "돋움",Dotum,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #555555;
 line-height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
#port_wrap ul li {
 height: 120px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#port_wrap .text{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="port_wrap">
 <ul>
    <li><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/142820969/eastasia.png" /><div class="text"><strong>동아시아문화도시 2014 광주; 아시아 무대 담당</strong><br />
     <span style="font-size: 13px">2014년 10월 | 광주문화예술회관</span></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```